# Boot to BIOS in VMWare Player

Tags: virtual-machine, bios, vmware

Is there an easy way to boot directly to the BIOS in VMWare Player so that you can select the OS and such?  Currently I use the keyboard commands to enter the bios, but it is hard to catch it in time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make it easier to access the BIOS setup screen, edit the configuration (.vmx) of the virtual machine and add or edit one of these options:

```
bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"
```

This forces entry to the BIOS setup at startup.

```
bios.bootDelay = "xxxx"
```

This adds a delay to the initial POST screen, showing it for longer and giving you more time to access the BIOS setup, where xxxx is the number of milliseconds to show the POST screen (There are 1000 milliseconds in a second.). The maximum value for the boot delay is 10000 milliseconds or 10 seconds.

Source: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004129

I just tried the 1st option, after adding it the VM will boot into BIOS directly, and VMWare player will change it to FALSE automatically after 1 boot.